# UI issue when using hardware keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, ios9, uikeyboard

In my app I've table views with several text views and whenever I click on a textview it autoscrolls up for keyboard space which works fine, now the problem is when I connect a hardware keyboard and click on a textview it still scrolls up for keyboard space so there's a blank space left which is normally hidden when the keyboard is up in the app. When I connect the external keyboard the application can call `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` but can't call the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. Is there a we can avoid the blank space coming up?

Below is a sample code of how my keyboard notifications are handled

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification)
    {

        if myTextField.isFirstResponder {

            self.tableView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height

            if let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo
            {
                if let keyboardRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
                {
                    mainScrollView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height - keyboardRect.size.height
                    tableViewTopConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.size.height-myView.submitViewHeightConstraint.constant
                }
            }
        }
        else{

            self.mainScrollView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height

            if let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo
            {
                if let keyboardRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
                {
                   self.tableView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height + myView.frame.size.height - keyboardRect.size.height

                }
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification){
        tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 0.0
        tableView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height - myView.frame.size.height
        mainScrollView.frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to make sure your views only adjust when an actual on-screen keyboard is present is to instead respond to the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` notification. The other thing is you should not end up with any blank spaces if you are actually using the layout information in the notifications you are responding to. Are you using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`? This should allow you to avoid any blank spaces you would have if you try to hardcode the frame.

Comment: Yes, I'm using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey, I've added the code for keyboard notifications that I've used in my app.